# Linux Move files to their child directory in a loop

Tags: linux, bash

Can you please suggest efficient way to move files from one location to their sub directory in a loop.

Ex:

`/MY_PATH/User1/1234/Daily/abc.txt` to `/MY_PATH/User1/1234/Daily/Archive/abc.txt`

`/MY_PATH/User2/3456/Daily/def.txt` to `/MY_PATH/User2/3456/Daily/Archive/def.txt`

`/MY_PATH/User1/1111/Daily/hij.txt` to `/MY_PATH/User1/1111/Daily/Archive/hij.txt`

`/MY_PATH/User2/2222/Daily/def.txt` to `/MY_PATH/User2/2222/Daily/Archive/def.txt`

I started in this way, but need your suggestions and best way to write it:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1="/MyPath/"

subs= `ls $dir1`

for i in $subs; do
  mv $dir1/$i/*/Daily $dir1/$i/*/Daily/Archive 
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My one line bash

```
for dir in $(
    find MY_PATH -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name Daily
  );do
    mkdir -p $dir/Archives
    find $dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name Archives \
        -exec mv -t $dir/Archives {} +
  done
```

To quickly test:

```
mkdir -p MY_PATH/User{1,2,3,4}/{1234,2346,3333,2323}/Daily 
touch MY_PATH/User{1,2,3,4}/{1234,2346,3333,2323}/Daily/{abc,bcd,def,feg,fds}.txt
for dir in $( find MY_PATH -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name Daily );do
  mkdir -p $dir/Archives; find $dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name Archives \
  -exec mv -t $dir/Archives {} + ; done
ls -lR MY_PATH
```

This seem match OP's request

#### For more robust solution

There is a solution wich work with spaces somewhere in path...

Edited to include @mklement0's well pointed suggestion.

```
while IFS= read dir;do
    mkdir -p "$dir"/Archives
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name Archives \
        -exec mv -t "$dir/Archives" {} +
  done < <(
    find MY_PATH -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name Daily
)
```

Same demo;

```
mkdir -p MY_PATH/User{1,2,3,"4 3"}/{1234,"23 6",3333,2323}/Daily
touch MY_PATH/User{1,2,3,"4 3"}/{1234,"23 6",3333,2323}/Daily/{abc,"b c",def,hgz0}.txt
while read dir;do mkdir -p "$dir"/Archives;find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \
  ! -name Archives -exec mv -t "$dir/Archives" {} +; done < <(
  find MY_PATH -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d -name Daily )
ls -lR MY_PATH
```

Comment: **Nota**: Syntax `for var in $(find ...)` would only work if there is no special chars or spaces in whole path.

Comment: The robust solution is nice, but you should use `IFS= read -r dir`, otherwise filenames such as "trailing spaces   " and "a\b test" will trip you up.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
dir1="/MyPath"

for d in "$dir1"/*/*/Daily/; do
  [[ -d $d ]] || break # break, if no subdirectories match
  for f in "$d"/*; do # loop over files in */*/Daily/
    [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue # skip non-files or if nothing matches
    mv "$f" "$d"/Archive/
  done
done
```

- `"$dir1"*/*/Daily/` matches all *grandchild* subdirectories of `$dir1`; thanks to the terminating `/`, only *directories* match; note that, as a result, `$d` ends in `/`.

  - <sup>Note that `$d` therefore ends in `/`, and, strictly speaking, needs no `/` later on when synthesizing paths with it (e.g., `"$d"/*`), but doing so does no harm and helps readability, as @4ae1e1 points out in a comment.</sup>
- `[[ -d $d ]] || break` ensures that the loop is exited if no grandchild directories match (by default, a glob (pattern) that has no matches is passed *as is* to the loop).
- `for f in "$d"*` loops over all entries (files and/or subdirs.) in `$d`:

  - `[[ -f "$f" ]] || continue` ensures that only *files* are processed or, in the event that *nothing* matches, the loop is exited.
  - `mv "$f" "$d"/Archive/` then moves each file to subdir. `Archive`.

Comment: But how does your answer work? You're only moving top level files in `dir1` and not touching files deep in the directory.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the now deleted comment about `ARG_MAX` — never realized that until you pointed out. (Just for the record: shell builtins and not affected by `ARG_MAX`.)

Comment: Well, if you look at the examples given, you can see that `dir1` is `/MyPath` and the files to be moved are three levels down the directory tree: `/MY_PATH/User1/1111/Daily/hij.txt`.

Comment: @4ae1e1: Thanks - guess I read the question sloppily - back to the drawing board...

Comment: Now your `"$d"*` actually includes `"${d}Archive/"`.

Comment: @4ae1e1: I appreciate your persistence - hopefully fixed now.

Comment: One minor point: although `$d` ends with `/`, I would still write `${d}/*` instead of `${d}*` and `${d}/Archive` instead of `${d}Archive`. 1. It doesn't hurt to have an extra `/`; 2. It's more human readable; 3. If you later change your mind and omit that `/` from `$d`, you don't need to hunt down every omission of that `/`.

Comment: @4ae1e1: Point taken, but I just can't bring myself to put up with `//`. How about `${d%/}/`?

Comment: Why can't you put up with `//`? They're not even in the output.

Comment: @4ae1e1: I was half-kidding - just a pedantic aversion, I suppose, but I feel like letting my hair down tonight, so I've taken your advice and updated my answer accordingly (with a note).

Comment: Thanks, I know, it does suck when I see `//` in my tty (worse still: `bin/../lib`, and things like that), but I'm happy to use them when they are under the rug.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the directory structure is as you have shown in your examples, i.e.

```
MY_PATH/
    subdir-level-1/
        subdir-level-2/
            Daily/
                files
                Archive/
```

Here's what you can do:

```
shopt -s nullglob # defend against globbing failure -- inspired by mklement0's answer
root="/MyPath"
for dir in "${root}"/*/*/Daily/; do
    mkdir -p "${dir}/Archive" # if Archive might not exist; to be pedantic you should look at David C. Rankin's answer for error handling, but usually we know what we're doing so that's not necessary
    find "${dir}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t "${dir}/Archive"
done
```

The reason I use `find` and `xargs` is to save a few processes; you can as well move files in each `${dir}` one by one.

---

Update: @mklement0 suggested that `find "${dir}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t "${dir}/Archive"` can be further improved to

```
find "${dir}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -t "${dir}/Archive" +
```

which is a very good point.

Comment: @mklement0 Using `exec +` is a good point. However, I'm afraid the second point is wrong, because the target directory is not `"$dir/Archive"`, but rather, `"$dir/$subdir1/$subdir2/Archive"`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks, that's why I deleted my comment; but to reinforce the 1st point: Combining `find` with `xargs`is an efficient approach; you can make it more efficient by using `-exec mv -t "$dir/Archive" {} +` instead of piping to `xargs`.

Comment: I couldn't come up with an _efficient_ one-liner, but here's at least _a_ one-liner: `find "$dir" -mindepth 4 -maxdepth 4  -regex '.*/Daily/.*' -type f -execdir mv -t Archive {} \;` - note that using `+` instead of `\;` makes no difference here: due to  `-execdir`, the command is invoked _once per matching filename_.

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah, thought about that, but too many processes kinda defeat the purpose. In one respect that's better though: no need to store `"${root}"/*/*/Daily/` in memory.

Comment: Wait, wait! It's all so simple: `find "$dir" -mindepth 4 -maxdepth 4  -regex '.*/Daily/.*' -type f -exec sh -c 'mv -t "$(dirname "$1")"/Archive "$@"' _ {} +`

Comment: No, there will only be a _single_ invocation of `sh` (due to `-exec` with `+`), and therefore only a _single_ invocation of `dirname` (unless you have a gazillion matching files).

Comment: @mklement0 I guess previously I wasn't able to wrap my head around your single invocation of `dirname`. Why would you assume each invocation of `sh` is fed with files with the same `dirname` so that you can get away with the `dirname "$1"`?

Comment: Dang! I keep forgetting that there are _2_ levels of ancestral directories involved; so, yet again: thanks, excellent point: I guess the `-execdir` solution is the closest we'll get to a one-liner - I do wish that `-execdir... +` were capable of _batched_ invocations based on grouping matches from the same directory...

Comment: @mklement0 You know what, we can write that `for ...; do find ... -exec ... +; done` on one line and call that a one-liner... (Just kidding.)

Comment: :) + for a solid answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you. It's been an interesting discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for, and if not present, create the destination directory before moving the file to `Archive`. If you cannot create the directory (due to permissions or otherwise), you skip the move. The following does not assume any limitation on depth, but will omit any directory containing `Archive` as an intermediate subdirectory:

```
oldifs="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(find /MY_PATH -type f); do
    [[ "$i" =~ Archive ]] && continue
    [ -d "${i%/*}/Archive" ] || mkdir -p "${i%/*}/Archive"
    [ -d "${i%/*}/Archive" ] || { 
        printf "error: unable to create '%s'\n" "${i%/*}/Archive"
        continue
    }
    mv -fv "$i" "${i/Daily/Daily\/Archive}"
done
IFS="$oldifs"
```

**Output when run**

```
$ bash archive_daily.sh
mv -fv /MY_PATH/User1/1111/Daily/hij.txt   /MY_PATH/User1/1111/Daily/Archive/hij.txt
mv -fv /MY_PATH/User1/1234/Daily/abc.txt   /MY_PATH/User1/1234/Daily/Archive/abc.txt
mv -fv /MY_PATH/User2/3456/Daily/def.txt   /MY_PATH/User2/3456/Daily/Archive/def.txt
mv -fv /MY_PATH/User2/2222/Daily/def.txt   /MY_PATH/User2/2222/Daily/Archive/def.txt
```

**Note:** you can limit/tighten the file selection by adjusting the call to `find` populating the for loop (e.g. `-name` or `-iname`). This simply checks/moves every file to its `Archive` folder. To limit to only files with the `.txt` extension, you can specify `find /MY_PATH -type f -name "*.txt"`. To limit to only files in the `/MY_PATH/User1` and `/MY_PATH/User2`directories with a `.txt` extension, use `find /MY_PATH/User[12] -type f -name "*.txt"`.

**Note2:** when looping on filenames, the paths & filenames should not contain non-standard characters for the current locale. Certainly you should not have the `'\n'` as a character in your filename. Setting `IFS` is required to protect against **word splitting** on spaces in either the path or filename.

Comment: [Best not to use `for` for parsing command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).
Since your `find` command is not depth-limited, you could end up matching existing files in `Archive` subdirectories.
You should output error messages to stderr.
Quibble: The term of art in Bash is _word splitting_, not _field splitting_.

Comment: No quibbling on either point -- good catch on both. The difficulty with the `find` limitation is that finding all files beneath some directory `/MY_PATH` necessarily involves using `find` when the depths are unknown. While the question gives the example `/MY_PATH/User[12]/*/*.txt`, I was hesitant to limit to `-maxdepth` because there was no indication there wouldn't also be  `/MY_PATH/User[12]/*/prjA/*.txt`, etc.. With no defined **stem** in the path to check against `-path "/MY_PATH/x" -prune "/MY_PATH/x/y"` I overlooked the existing `Archive` issue. The continue should handle it.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n'` still fails when there are newlines in paths, which is a perfectly legit path character. They never happen in real world, though, unless you have malicious users.

Comment: And congratulations on successful string manipulations with pure Bash. (One nitpick: `$i` doesn't need to be quoted between `[[ ]]`, since word splitting is not performed.)

Comment: Yes, that's just habit. And no quotes needed when surrounded by braces or with command substitution. But my fingers work faster than my brain at times and they just quote because they have been engrained to quote, which, I guess is better then the other way around `:p`

Comment: Personally, I only double-quote inside `[[ ... ]]` when necessary (to specify _literals_ on the RHS of `==` and `=~`), but I can see how training oneself to _always_ double-quote so as not to have to remember exceptions makes sense - Bash's different parsing contexts (commands, `[[ ... ]]`, `(( ... ))`) with their differing rules can get confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Since you said *efficient*, anything with a subshell will fail in funny ways with lots of entries. You're better off using `xargs`:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1="/MyPath/"
find $dir1 -name Daily -type d -depth 3 | while read i
do
    pushd .
    cd $i
    mkdir Archive
    find . -type f -depth 1 | xargs -J {} mv {} Archive
    popd
done
```

The outer `find` will look for you `Daily` directories. It's very specific in that they have to be at a certain depth and directories, not regular files. The results gets piped into `read`, where each directory is entered, `Archive` is created, and files batch-copied with `xargs ... mv`. Complete file lists and directory lists are never stored in memory, so it scales very well.

Comment: I think you mean `mv -t Archive`. By the way, this is not safe against malicious filenames (e.g., with newlines), even if you quote `"$i"`.

Comment: Good catch. I switched to `xargs -J` .

Comment: Handling special characters varies by platform. Not all `xargs` implementations support specifying a delimiter, and not all find implementations have `-fls`.

Comment: `-J` by itself is still not safe with respect to filenames with embedded spaces; for a robust solution use find's `-print0` and xarg's `-0` option. Also,  `-depth <n>` doesn't work with _GNU_ `find`; use `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`. Please double-quote `$dir1` and `$i`.

Comment: No `xargs` delimiter would help you if the directory names returned by `find $dir1 -name Daily -type d -depth 3` are allowed to contain arbitrary characters (as far as they are allowed in filenames). To use `xargs` with your first `find` command you have to wrap the body of your `while` loop in a function and export it.

Comment: @mklement0 "for a robust solution use find's -print0 and xarg's -0 option" Or you can use GNU Parallel, which is a super beefed up xargs. My xargs skills deteriorated so badly after I learned to use `parallel`.

Comment: @4ae1e1: Thanks for the `parallel` tip.  `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ...` should work with _all_ legal filenames, right?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: The question is tagged `linux`, so you should assume _GNU_ utilities. It's great to provide a portable answer, but yours currently isn't (it actually _breaks_ on Linux), and it's not robust.